# How to test PLL for step input change in phase

Tags: circuit-analysis, control-system, matlab, pll, phase

I wrote a simulation for second-order PLL and I would like to test it with an input to see whether my PLL can track the phase.  I would like to change the phase of my sinusoidal signal with step with magnitude 10 rad. Therefore that's what I did:

```
  F=60;
    t=0:Ts:2-Ts;
    idx=find(t>=0);
    theta(idx)=pi/180*10*ones(1,length(idx));
    in=sin(2*pi*F*t+theta);
    out=pll(in);
    plot(t,out,t,theta)
```

However, these two phases differ a lot. I am wondering can anyone tell me if there is any problem with the above script.

Here are the commands inside the for loop:

```
Error(ii)=Kd*in_norm(ii)*VCO_out(ii-1);     % Calculate the Error

prop_out(ii)=Kp*Error(ii);

integ_out(ii)=KI*Error(ii)*Ts+integ_out(ii-1);

lf_out(ii)=integ_out(ii)+prop_out(ii);

phi_out(ii)=lf_out(ii)*Ts*K0*2*pi+phi_out(ii-1);

VCO_out(ii)=sin(2*pi*Fout*(ii-2)*Ts+phi_out(ii));
```

[image]

Comment: You should add a picture of the input/output plot, and give more details of your PLL implementation.

Comment: I implemented a PLL by using first order loop filter as one proportional and one integral term. My sole question is do you think above code is creating step change in phase correctly if it is correct I will suspect that my code is wrong.

Comment: It sure would be easy to determine this if you just showed the simulation results including the signals theta, in, out vs. t.  Also, what sort of phase detector does this PLL use?

Comment: I get different graph for different parameters but this looks to be the best one,

Comment: The input is not even changing in the image you show

Comment: I would first make sure you can get a simulation with the output tracking the input, with no time-dependent phase shift.  The input should be oscillating at a frequency and the output should follow it.  You will want to run the simulation for probably 10+ cycles (it takes some cycles for the PLL to lock on). From here add the theta as a function of t*constant.  Increase the constant to see what level of constant linear phase shift your PLL can track.

Comment: @jbord39  I am sorry guy the above figure is the output phase vs time and input phase vs time. The one that is not changing is the input phase which is just step signals

Comment: add the statements you use to find the phase and/or other variables, and perhaps a time domain plot would not hurt either.

Comment: I added the statement inside the for loop for everything loop filter , VCO and phase detector. I am also wondering if I want the plot for reference phase vs time should I plot                                                                                                   plot(t, theta)    or plot(t,2*pi*F*t+theta)   since 2*pi*F*t is also kind of part of phase?

Comment: the phase shift is the added component, theta.  For example, if you have a free running sine wave, and it had no phase shift, you would expect for the phase shift to remain constant, not oscillate with each cycle.

Comment: OK, thanks so you think it should be plot(t, theta) for correct phase reference vs time. but based on the commands I added can you tell me what is wrong with the program why it is not tracking properly ?

Comment: As I said earlier time domain plots of all pertinent variables would help a lot.  See if you can get the PLL to lock on without an additional phase shift.  Then see if the PLL can lock on to a linear phase shift.  Finally see if the PLL can lock onto this additional sinusoidal phase shift which you are giving it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run the simulation longer, at a minimum (there could also be issues with the code).  But take for example the image I attached below.

[image: basic pll lock on]

You can see the input (top signal) and output (bottom signal).  The bottom signal does not even begin to lock on until the second period.  Even then it takes some time for it to properly lock on (10+ cycles, not shown).

I would also just implement theta as a function of time, rather than mapping it to the linear indices of time (it's simpler to me):

```
F=60;
step=1/(f*4)
t=0:step:1; #240 datapoints, 60 cycles of runtime
theta(t)=t*720; #linear phase shift of 2 cycles over 60 cycles
in=sin(2*pi*F*t+theta);
out=pll(in);
plot(t,out,t,theta)
```

I don't have access to MATLAB so I can't check if this is correct.
Simulation results would be nice to help debug as well.

Comment: As I mentioned above there is labeling problem in the graph and the above graph represents output and input phase as a function of time. That's why input is not changing.